# How to blink cursor in input text box after changed tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

WHenever I will click the button, in the input field, the cursor is blinking. But the problem is, if I go to another tab and if i will come back to this tab, that time the cursor is not in the position. I need to click the input field again.

- After went to another tab also, if I come back, the input field should get blinking.

Please look at the below link,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4ds9627/)

Here, I have 3 Tabs. I have input field in the 3rd Tab.

- If I click add new button, one input field will get open.
- Then I click 1st or 2nd tab, and i will come back to the same 3rd tab. That time, cursor is not blinking.

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.directive('tabs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">' +
              '<li ng-class="{active: activeTab == tab}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs"><a ng-click="setActive(tab)">{{tab}}</a></li>' +
              '</ul>' + 
              '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.tabs = [];
      $scope.activeTab = '';
      
      $scope.setActive = function(tab) {
        $scope.activeTab = tab;
      };
      
      this.register = function(tabName) {
        $scope.tabs.push(tabName);
        if (!$scope.activeTab) {
          $scope.setActive(tabName);
        }
      };
      
      this.isActive = function(tabName) {
        return tabName == $scope.activeTab;
      };

      $scope.myVar = false;
      $scope.toggleTeamField = function() {
          $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
          $scope.focus = !$scope.focus;
      };
    }
  }  
}).directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^tabs',
      template: '<div class="tab-pane" ng-show="isActive(title)" ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsController) {
        tabsController.register(scope.title);
        scope.isActive = function(tabName) {
          return tabsController.isActive(tabName);
        };
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <tabs>
      <pane title="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</pane>
      <pane title="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</pane>
      <pane title="Tab 3">
         <input placeholder="Enter your teams name" my-focus="{{focus}}"
                ng-model="team_input" ng-show="myVar"  
                class="team_input"  type="text" name="team_input" required/>
         <button ng-click="toggleTeamField()">Add New</button>
      </pane>
    </tabs>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your input field an `id`:

```html
<input 
  id="team_input"
  placeholder="Enter your teams name" 
  my-focus="{{focus}}" 
  ng-model="team_input" 
  ng-show="myVar"  
  class="team_input"  
  type="text"
  name="team_input" 
  required
/>
```

you can autofocus it on tab change like this:

```js
link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsController) {
  tabsController.register(scope.title);
  scope.isActive = function (tabName) {
    document.getElementById("team_input").focus();
    return tabsController.isActive(tabName);
  };
}
```